# Is it possible to use multi conditions in PHP switch resultant with multi actions (executible codes)?

Tags: php, switch-statement, executable, conditional-statements

Is it possible to use multi conditional statement in PHP (switch) resultant with multi conditional (executable codes)? The code might be look like this:

In case of `$fifth` only was 9, `$fifth  -= $fifth;` only must be executed and vice verse with `$fourth` and `$third`.

```
 switch ($fifth xor $fourth xor $third) {
     case '9':
         $fifth  -= $fifth;
         $fourth -= $fourth;
         $third  -= $third;
         break;
     default:
         $fifth  = $fifth;
         $fourth = $fourth;
         $third  = $third;
 }
```

Comment: It will evaluate the logical expression `fifth xor $fourth xor $third`, which evaluates to either `true` or `false`.

Comment: @Barmar which will always jump to `default`, as it **never** evaluates to `9`.

Comment: Are you trying to simplify `if ($fifth == 9 xor $fourth == 9 xor $third == 9)`

Comment: @Barmar: Yes, but the problem that I have a for loop that required to check multi conditional values every time for every variable $fifth == 9, 10, 11, 12 and switch statement is more comfortable.

Comment: If you have to do the same thing with multiple variables, maybe they should be in an array. You could also write a function that takes them all as parameters and does the comparison.

Comment: Please tell your problem, not what you think is the solution.

Comment: @Bart: My problem is how to code for loop to give me a certain sequence of results. check this out http://goo.gl/rrRaR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot do it like that. You'll have to use separate `if` statements:

```
if ($fifth == 9) {
  $fifth -= $fifth;
}

if ($fourth == 9) {
....
```

By the way, `$fifth -= $fifth` equals `$fifth = 0`, which is more efficient and readable.

Comment: Yes, but the problem that I have a for loop that required to check multi conditional values every time for every variable $fifth == 9, 10, 11, 12 and switch statement is more comfortable.  Thank you for the last note :)

Comment: Something like `if($fifth >=9 && $fifth <= 12) {}` ?

Comment: That would be great, and it did short hand my statement: now it's just if ($fifth >= 9 && $fifth <= 12){$fifth  = $fifth - 9;}

Answer (score 0):

You could use this little goodie

```
function isOneOf (){
    $args = func_get_args();
    $test = array_shift($args);
    return in_array($test, $args);  
}
```

Use it like this:

```
if (isOneOf(9, $fifth, $forth, $third)){
   // code if one parameters equals 9 (except the first)
}
```

as an alternative to

```
if ($fifth == 9 || $forth == 9 || $third == 9){
   ... code
}
```

Comment: It worked!, but.. I have a loop, and if I activate it, I'll get a fatal error! it says" Cannot redeclare isOneOf() (previously declared in..." what to do!?

Comment: Define it outside your loop or if you want to add it to your bat belt throw it in a utils.php file and include it at the top of any page you want to use it on.

Comment: It went perfect as you considered, but it didn't match my needs! What I needed is multiconditional statement leading to multi execution codes inside the if statement using the variables names, if $fifth was true, then execute the code belongs to it only like $fifth  -= $fifth; as an example, and/or if the $fourth was true also, then the code belongs to it only need to be executed like $fourth -= $fourth; as another example..